# Apple sign in is not working on testflight

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, authentication, apple-sign-in

Currently, I'm stuck on an issue which is regarding the apple sign in. As you all know from iOS 13, apple sign-in is mandatory with social logins. The problem I'm having is I implemented apple sign-in which is working in debug mode but when I submit build on test flight It doesn't work. It seems as the button has it is apple's bug. Kindly Guide me to resolve this issue or any other way out

Thanks

**Code for Apple SignIn**

```
@IBAction func appleIDSignin(_ sender:UIButton){
SVProgressHUD.show()
self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
currentAppleUser { (userFound) in
    if userFound {
        let userName = KeychainItem.currentUserNameIdentifier
        print(userName)
        let email = KeychainItem.currentEmailIdentifier
        self.socialLogin(Name: userName, Email: email, isMale: 1)
    } else if userFound == false {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            self.handleAppleIDRequest()
        }
    }
}

func handleAppleIDRequest(){
    let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
    let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
    request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
    let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
    authorizationController.delegate = self
    authorizationController.performRequests()
}
```

**Checking current user**

```
func currentAppleUser( completionHandler:@escaping(_ userFound:Bool)->()){
let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
appleIDProvider.getCredentialState(forUserID: KeychainItem.currentUserIdentifier) { (credentialState, error) in
    switch credentialState {
    case .authorized:
        print("User Valid")
        if KeychainItem.currentUserNameIdentifier == "" || KeychainItem.currentEmailIdentifier == "" {
            completionHandler(false)
        } else {
            completionHandler(true)
        }
        break // The Apple ID credential is valid.
    case .revoked:
        print("revoked")
        completionHandler(false)
        
    case .notFound:
        print("notFound")
        completionHandler(false)
        // The Apple ID credential is either revoked or was not found, so show the sign-in UI.
    
    default:
        break
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to open sandbox account for this, you will get or make one email and passsword so you can test it. Same as apple pay. You can create sandbox users from test flight.

Comment: how to create that sandbox account ? I already included apple sign-in in capabilities tab

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/sandbox-testing/
Here you have all the details about it. In Production everything will be fine, but in test environments you need to have this account either for sign in or Apple Pay.

Comment: do you really think it will resolve my issue ? because my apple sign-in button working perfectly fine in xcode but not working in testflight